# Identifying AVI files with missing index

Tags: ffmpeg, avi

I am looking for a bash scriptable method to identify AVI files that are missing their index.

These are truncated AVI files that are still playable, albeit with some issues.
Until now the only reliable methods are to open the AVI in VirtualDub (which requests to rederive keyframe flags, and then save with stream copy creates a repaired AVI) or VLC which prompts for creation of an index for seekable playback, but it doesn't save it.

`ffmpeg -i bad.avi -codec copy good.avi` creates a repaired AVI. And this is scriptable.
But I want to identify only the bad files and feed them to such a repaire script, not waste processing on good files.

I tried something like `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=index -of default=nw=1 file.avi` but it yields "index=0" for both good and bad files. (maybe I misunderstood)

Can such files be identified with `ffmpeg` and if yes, how?

---

I prepared myself a testcase like this: `original.avi` (intact, with index file) and `test.avi` which is a truncated version (without index).
Created with `dd if=original.avi of=test.avi bs=1M count=X` (where X is smaller then the filesize of the original).

*The output of ffprobe:*

```
Input #0, avi, from 'original.avi': 
Duration: 01:54:27.87, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 847 kb/s 
Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (DIV3 / 0x33564944), yuv420p, 640x352, 646 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc 
Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s

Input #0, avi, from 'test.avi':
Duration: 01:47:10.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 847 kb/s 
Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (DIV3 / 0x33564944), yuv420p, 640x352, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc 
Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
```

Additionally, the command `ffprobe -hide_banner -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream -of default test.avi` yields the following fields as different: **duration**, **duration_ts**, **bitrate** when compared to the output on `original.avi`.

**bitrate** is listed as ***N/A*** for `test.avi`, but this is unreliable.
I tested on multiple files and this indicator most often behaves as a false positive.

Tested using ffmpeg generations 3, 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: Is the stream truly "missing"? If so, what's this knowledge based on? Or is it damaged? If it's damaged, how do the damages look when you're trying to play the file?

Comment: The stream is present. The AVI index (stored at end of file) is missing.

Comment: Well, you definitely misunderstood the command you tried using then - that's for stream indexes. I don't think ffprobe has capapbility you're seeking. As for processing, the command with codec copy doesn't reencode, so it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Unfortunately just ffmpeg -codec copy doesn't solve the problem entirely. See my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70913135/how-to-re-derive-keyframes-in-damaged-avi-using-ffmpeg-vcodec-copy